# Wordpress and a Rails app coexisting on the same domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, php, ruby-on-rails

We've got wordpress installed on a standard LAMP setup and then a Rails app with Heroku.

Is there any way to have them on the same domain? Trying to avoid having the wordpress app (which powers the marketing site) on `example.com` and then the Rails app at `app.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Rails app could be deployed to sub-URI (e.g. `http://example.com/railsapp/`), there is [Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) for such setup.